# How to make an Installer App for Android

Tags: android, installation, apk

I am thinking about making an app that can install it's own apps, something like the Google Play does. I want the app to run at the system's startup and check in my server for a new version, if it detects a new one, it will download and install it, upgrading the old app.

I want to do it myself, because I don't want to place the app in google play since I am testing a new business model for app sharing and selling.

Is it there any documentations or APIs for this? I couldn't find much things online, but I found many installer apps, just not so many docs.... any help is most welcome!

EDIT:

To make it clear....APIs for downloading content, making an App run at startup and etc. is easy to find online, but I can't find an API for installing an APK, something that gets an APK and transforms it into an installed app.

Comment: "Is it there any documentations or APIs for this?" -- for what, specifically?

Comment: On how to make an installer app...downloading an APK from the any server is just like downloading any file, so basically I think the only API I need to know is how to make an APK be installed right?

Comment: APK -> App...I think that's all I can't find out there

Comment: When you used a search engine to look for `android install app programmatically`, `android install app api`, or similar search queries, what did you learn?

Comment: I searched for `how to make an installer app for android`...let me try your way :)....sometimes the hard thing is to know the right words for searching...

Comment: Now I could find some links to the Intent method using `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)`, will this just open the Android Market or will it really install it silently (considering the app is rooted)?

Comment: First, apps aren't rooted. Devices are rooted. Second, you're not going to find official documentation for silent installation on rooted devices, simply because that's not supported. There are various recipes floating around that do that, and you'll find them on discussion boards and the like.

Comment: Oh, I thought the app could ask for root permission from the user, and once it gets it, it could go forward with the installation

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to achieve it.

### 1. Implement it by yourself

a. Create a service and register a BroadcastReceiver to the Android android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED system event.

b. download the apk if there is a new version

c. use below code to install the apk, which will override the current app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(file:///pathToApk));
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

### 2. there is a handy open source library

Please find it from https://code.google.com/p/auto-update-apk-client/

Comment: "compile and upload the application to our server"...didnt like it :P but I liked the options! many thanks

Comment: Will this intent open some other app externally to install the APK or will it run silently?